# Run several functions concurrently (threading)

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to run different python functions at the same time. Each function is a different algorithmic trading strategy completely independent of each other. I want to avoid to open several Spyder instances at the same time (I experienced several times Spyder crashing down when having 5+ instances open and running, although my PC is certainly not very powerful).

I use threading but it seems that only the first code is running (i.e. `t1`).

What am I possibly doing wrong?

```
#set the path to working directory
from os import chdir, getcwd
#C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python for Finance\MACD_Strategy\Alpaca_MACD
wd = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python for Finance\\MACD_Strategy\\Alpaca_MACD"
chdir(wd)
from MACD_Alpaca_5min_15min_LS_Portfolio_System_Yahoo import MACD_Alpaca_algo
from MACD_reverse_Alpaca_5min_15min_LS_Portfolio_System_Yahoo import MACD_2_Alpaca_algo
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target = MACD_Alpaca_algo())
t2 = threading.Thread(target = MACD_2_Alpaca_algo())


t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Does `MACD_Alpaca_algo()` return another function, or is `MACD_Alpaca_algo` itself the function you want the thread to run?

Comment: You can refer [this link for multiple parallel task in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function before spawning the thread.
Here' the right way to do it.

```py
t1 = threading.Thread(target = MACD_Alpaca_algo)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = MACD_2_Alpaca_algo)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Is threading for this type of application (several independent algos analysing markets every 5 minutes) the right approach in general, or is the approach suggested by @Akash senta more appropriate (concurrent.futures, multiprocessing). Thanks

Comment: It depends on what your algorithms are doing. Play with both threads and processes and decide for yourself.